# How to open a file without extension by URL deployed at JBoss

Tags: java, url, tomcat, jboss, jboss5.x

Require to read a flat file that do not have any extension through URL, couldn't get this as browser(404) and java(FileNotFoundException) not taking the file as a resource to open.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URLTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
/*Block 1: Reading a file "test.txt" (WITH extension) that works */
    try{   System.out.println("Block 1");
           URL url1 = new URL("http://localhost:8080/CtxPath/test.txt"); //file test.txt available at WebContent
           BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url1.openStream()));
           String inputLine;
           while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
           System.out.println(inputLine);
           in.close();
       } catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

/* Block 2 : Reading the other one "test" (WITHOUT extension) that throws Exception */
    try{    System.out.println("Block 2");
            URL url2 = new URL("http://localhost:8080/CtxPath/test"); ////file test also available at WebContent
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url2.openStream()));
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(inputLine);
            in.close();
       }  catch(Exception e) {  e.printStackTrace(); }
 }
}
```

#### Output

```
Block 1 
File content from test.txt read successfully.
Block 2
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://localhost:8080/CtxPath/test
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1624)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1037)
    at URLTest.main(URLTest.java:28)
```

Jboss 5.1 Java 1.7

Getting exception on open URL for the file(test) without extension. The other file with .txt extension(test.txt) that placed in the same location with similar content opens without any issues.

Is there any app specific or server specific config to do for allowing the file without extension to be served?

Comment: are you able to reach the second file using a browser?

Comment: @mxb No, that returns 404. But sure the file is placed on that path.

Comment: Why? Is providing a correct URL really so much trouble?

Answer (score 1):

In the servlet container implementation, things without suffix "test" is not treat as file, but treat as servlet mapping.
You can download tomcat source code, the logic for this is similar in jboss, and take a look.
And I don't think you should make a file without suffix, if you really need to, then put it under WEB-INF/xxx/, then use a servlet to help read it.

Comment: Getting Null at servlet too. 
While checking the resources at "/WEB-INF", context.getResourcePaths("/WEB-INF") doesn't show the file without extension. Listed only the other resources as follows 
[/WEB-INF/lib/, /WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml, /WEB-INF/test.txt, /WEB-INF/classes/, /WEB-INF/web.xml]

Comment: Ok, so add some suffix ~~

Answer (score 0):

Java is simply calling the URL. It cares not whether it has a `.` in the path. The server you are calling, on the other hand, /may/ have logic which determines how it attempts to fulfill the request. The `FileNotFoundException` indicates a `404` http status code was returned.

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible that file does have extension that you may not be able to see because Operating system settings have hide the extensions or some rules on your server may causing it to return 404. Java does not give file not found exception because of extension.

Please let us know the issue, when you resolve it.

Comment: Try to print name of all the files in the directory and verify if the path you are using is exactly same as the path you are specifying. you  can use the following code snippet or some thing like this to list all files: {File [] files=directory.listFiles();
  for(File file:files){
   System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
  }}

Comment: Yes it lists the file, here is the output of 'path.toAbsolutePath()' for the "WebContent" dir,
D:\workspace\eclipse-jee-kepler-SR1-win32-x86_64\CtxPath\WebContent\index.jsp
D:\workspace\eclipse-jee-kepler-SR1-win32-x86_64\CtxPath\WebContent\META-INF
**D:\workspace\eclipse-jee-kepler-SR1-win32-x86_64\CtxPath\WebContent\test**
D:\workspace\eclipse-jee-kepler-SR1-win32-x86_64\CtxPath\WebContent\test.txt
D:\workspace\eclipse-jee-kepler-SR1-win32-x86_64\CtxPath\WebContent\WEB-INF